# Package manager has died while checking permission

Tags: applications, permissions

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.checkPermission(ApplicationPackageManager.java:427)

Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)

Can anyone help me what does this mean and how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

A `DeadObjectException` can occur if two Android processes are communicating with each other and one of them dies while transferring data to the other. The other process will then throw a `DeadObjectException`.

In your case the "other" process was the PackageManager process which was communicating to a second process - may be a system service for listing packages?

There is not an easy solution how to prevent such an error. The only chance you have is by checking the `adb logcat` output for errors when you access the package manager.

The reason why the other process (whatever process it is) fails may be corrupt data.